# How can I check my framerate in Microsoft Flight Simulator?

Tags: microsoft-flight-simulator

I finally got Microsoft Flight Simulator to run, and I want to figure out how badly it performs on my computer (the sim informs me every launch that my specs are sub-minimum). How can I check my framerate in the sim?

Answer (score 9):

You can switch on FPS display in developer settings (Options -> General -> Developers -> enable Developer mode -> new menu bar appears -> Options -> Display FPS). However, its a rather huge overlay and probably not what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You also have the option of using the Steam overlay (if that's where you bought it), some third party software such as FRAPS, or the overlay that comes from your GPU software (GeForce Experience or Radeon Overlay), as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If you're playing on Steam, then as per this [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/209710/4-quick-ways-to-see-a-pc-game%E2%80%99s-fps-frames-per-second/#:%7E:text=Steam%27s%20In%2DGame%20Overlay&text=In%20Steam%20while%20no%20games,ll%20see%20the%20FPS%20counter), enabling the FPS option in steam before the game is opened worked for me:

> Valve recently added an FPS counter to Steam’s in-game overlay. In Steam (while no games are running), just head to Steam > Settings > In-Game and then pick a position for the FPS display from the “In-game FPS counter” dropdown.

Comment: Welcome to the site thin! Answers should contain all the relevant information in the body of the post, instead of just linking off to another resource saying "Find the answer here." I've edited your answer to demonstrate what I mean by this.The key information is now in the body of your post, but a user can visit the link if they just want some additional details. Whereas before they had no choice but to visit the link, since your answer didn't really contain any relevant information. Cheers!